# Nvidia surround with GTX 580

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have just received a second monitor. Can I run Nvidia surround (or any other alternatives) with just my 1 Nvidia GTX 580?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need two or more graphics cards (see info [here](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-580/specifications)).

> NVIDIA 3D Vision Surround require two or more graphics cards in NVIDIA SLI configuration [...]

Comment: Damn :( I was looking forward to playing on double monitors.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty cool! Don't have it at home but I got to mess around with it at bit at the office :)